# Flutter - AutofillGroup and Provider on a login form. How to save password on login successful

Tags: flutter, dart, mobile-development

Given a widget and using the provider package I would like to know if it's possible to prompt to save the credentials **only** on a successful event (ie: login).

Here is a relevant snippet of the code

```dart
Form _buildLoginAutofillForm() {
    final viewModel = context.read<LoginViewModel>();

    return Form(
      key: viewModel.loginFormKey,
      child: AutofillGroup(
        key: viewModel.autoFillGroupKey,
        child: Column(
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
          children: [
            Selector<LoginViewModel, bool>(
              selector: (p0, p1) => p1.isBusy,
              builder: (context, isBusy, child) => TextFormField(
                autofillHints: const [AutofillHints.email],
                textInputAction: TextInputAction.next,
                decoration: InputDecoration(
                  labelText:
                      AppLocalizations.of(context)!.loginPagePlaceholderEmail,
                ),
                enabled: !isBusy,
                keyboardType: TextInputType.emailAddress,
                enableSuggestions: false,
                autocorrect: false,
                controller: viewModel.usernameTextEditingController,
                validator: (value) {
                  if (value == null ||
                      value.isEmpty ||
                      !EmailValidator.validateEmail(value)) {
                    return AppLocalizations.of(context)!.formInvalidEmail;
                  }
                  return null;
                },
              ),
            ),
            Selector<LoginViewModel, bool>(
              selector: (p0, p1) => p1.isBusy,
              builder: (context, isBusy, child) => TextFormField(
                autofillHints: const [AutofillHints.password],
                decoration: InputDecoration(
                  labelText: AppLocalizations.of(context)!
                      .loginPagePlaceholderPassword,
                ),
                enabled: !isBusy,
                obscureText: true,
                enableSuggestions: false,
                autocorrect: false,
                controller: viewModel.passwordTextEditingController,
                textInputAction: TextInputAction.go,
                validator: (value) {
                  if (value == null || value.isEmpty) {
                    return AppLocalizations.of(context)!.formRequiredField;
                  }
                  return null;
                },
                onFieldSubmitted: (value) async {
                  await _subimtLoginForm(viewModel);
                },
              ),
            ),
            const SizedBox(height: 8.0),
            Selector<LoginViewModel, bool>(
              selector: (p0, p1) => p1.isBusy,
              builder: (context, isBusy, child) => FilledButton(
                onPressed: isBusy
                    ? null
                    : () async {
                        await _subimtLoginForm(viewModel);
                      },
                child:
                    Text(AppLocalizations.of(context)!.loginPageButtonSignIn),
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  Future _subimtLoginForm(LoginViewModel viewModel) async {
    if (!viewModel.loginFormKey.currentState!.validate()) {
      return false;
    }

    viewModel.loginFormKey.currentState!.save();
    await viewModel.login();
    return false;
  }
```

I'm facing a few issues here. The most important seems to be (not entirely sure) once the "isBusy" variable changes and notifies the TextFormField elements, the AutofillGroup is asking me to save the credentials. It doesn't matter if the login process is correct or not.

I'm laso experiencing the same if I call:

```dart
FocusScope.of(context).unfocus();
```

It may be the case I'm not getting how this is supposed to work. My goal is to have the autofill functionality but only save when a login is successful.

Answer (score 0):

I came up with some sort of solution, maybe useful for some:

Given there are a few [issues](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/118030) with this specific technology I tried to come up with some -workaround- to solve not only requesting to save the credentials on successful login but also to prevent the jump issue.

What I did is a combination of things.

- The Autofill now gets regenerated if the login credentials are
  correct (achieved via flag isLogged in).
- The flag controls the onDisposeAction
- To prevent prompting when the field focus is lost, I added some
  listeners
- After the login is done, before redirecting (I'm using a listener on
  my router) I recreate the autofill state and request a focus. When
  the view is disposed the prompt will be shown.
- I'm using some futures to avoid the jumpy animation, which seems to
  happen when the software keyboard is present and the prompt is
  displayed.

Code for the widget:

```dart
 Form _buildLoginAutofillForm() {
    final viewModel = context.read<LoginViewModel>();

    return Form(
      key: viewModel.loginFormKey,
      child: Selector<LoginViewModel, bool>(
        selector: (p0, p1) => p1.loggedIn,
        builder: (context, loggedIn, child) {
          // the autofill group will trigger the credentials storage on succesful login
          // one of the input fields will regain focus. Change the keyboard type to none to avoid jumpy bug
          return AutofillGroup(
            key: viewModel.autofillKey,
            onDisposeAction: loggedIn
                ? AutofillContextAction.commit
                : AutofillContextAction.cancel,
            child: Column(
              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
              children: [
                Selector<LoginViewModel, bool>(
                  selector: (p0, p1) => p1.isBusy,
                  builder: (context, isBusy, child) => TextFormField(
                    autofillHints: const [AutofillHints.email],
                    textInputAction: TextInputAction.next,
                    decoration: InputDecoration(
                      labelText: AppLocalizations.of(context)!
                          .loginPagePlaceholderEmail,
                    ),
                    enabled: !isBusy,
                    keyboardType: loggedIn
                        ? TextInputType.none
                        : TextInputType.emailAddress,
                    focusNode: viewModel.usernameFocusNode,
                    enableSuggestions: false,
                    autocorrect: false,
                    controller: viewModel.usernameTextEditingController,
                    validator: (value) {
                      if (value == null ||
                          value.isEmpty ||
                          !EmailValidator.validateEmail(value)) {
                        return AppLocalizations.of(context)!.formInvalidEmail;
                      }
                      return null;
                    },
                  ),
                ),
                Selector<LoginViewModel, bool>(
                  selector: (p0, p1) => p1.isBusy,
                  builder: (context, isBusy, child) => TextFormField(
                    autofillHints: const [AutofillHints.password],
                    decoration: InputDecoration(
                      labelText: AppLocalizations.of(context)!
                          .loginPagePlaceholderPassword,
                    ),
                    enabled: !isBusy,
                    keyboardType: loggedIn ? TextInputType.none : null,
                    focusNode: viewModel.passwordFocusNode,
                    obscureText: true,
                    enableSuggestions: false,
                    autocorrect: false,
                    controller: viewModel.passwordTextEditingController,
                    textInputAction: TextInputAction.go,
                    validator: (value) {
                      if (value == null || value.isEmpty) {
                        return AppLocalizations.of(context)!.formRequiredField;
                      }
                      return null;
                    },
                    onFieldSubmitted: (value) async {
                      await _subimtLoginForm(viewModel);
                    },
                  ),
                ),
                const SizedBox(height: 8.0),
                Selector<LoginViewModel, bool>(
                  selector: (p0, p1) => p1.isBusy,
                  builder: (context, isBusy, child) => FilledButton(
                    onPressed: isBusy || loggedIn
                        ? null
                        : () async {
                            await _subimtLoginForm(viewModel);
                          },
                    child: Text(
                        AppLocalizations.of(context)!.loginPageButtonSignIn),
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          );
        },
      ),
    );
  }

  Future<void> _subimtLoginForm(LoginViewModel viewModel) async {
    TextInput.finishAutofillContext(shouldSave: false);
    FocusScope.of(context).unfocus();
    if (!viewModel.loginFormKey.currentState!.validate()) {
      return;
    }
    viewModel.loginFormKey.currentState!.save();

    if (await viewModel.login()) {
      // give time to the UI to regenerate the autofill context and create a new
      // autofill state
      WidgetsBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback((_) async {
        // request focus (keyboard type will be set to none)
        // this recreates the autofill state and password save will be prompt
        // see focus node on viewmodel
        viewModel.passwordFocusNode.requestFocus();
        await Future.microtask(() => viewModel.finishLoginProcess());
      });
    }
  }
```

And on the View Model:

```dart
 LoginViewModel() {
    usernameFocusNode.addListener(focusListener);
    passwordFocusNode.addListener(focusListener);
  }

  void focusListener() {
    if (!_loggedIn) {
      TextInput.finishAutofillContext(shouldSave: false);
    }
  }
```